# Closing UIAlertView instead of using dissmissing

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uialertview

I have a question about how I close and release the custom designed `UIAlertView`. In my `UIAlertView`, i'm using the `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex` function; however, it only closes to the background, it doesn't close in real manner.

Does anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: please edit your question with code, that will better for us give you answer.

Answer (score 0):

How does it *close to the background*? I assume you are refering to the pointer of the UIAlertView is still valid after dismissing? In that case you need to `[myAlertView release];` to "make it go away completely".

Comment: also add myAlertView = nil; to badcat answer